# installation stopping at 51%

Tags: magento2, installation

During installation, using both FF and Chrome, trying new db's, clearing cache, all checks pass, but it stops at the same point each time. thank you for any help in the matter. First time using Magento, have semi-decent coding skills.

php version **5.6.27**

> Module 'Field_Productlist':
> Installing data...
> [ERROR] exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message >'Wrong entity ID' in /home/www/shop.****.co.uk/vendor/magento/module->eav/Setup/EavSetup.php:265

Stack trace:

> 0 /home/www/shop.****.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php(800): >Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product')
>
> 1 /home/www/shop.jlmk.co.uk/app/code/Field/Productlist/Setup/InstallData.php(77>): Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'featured', >Array)

long stack trace can be added

Comment: Try to download latest version of magento 2.1 and try.

Answer (score 0):

Can be for the memory limit. Change this value on php.ini:

`memory_limit=2048M`

I suppose all PHP settings magento checks are green.

Comment: yeah all checks are good, was able to load a base 2,1,2 in previous installations. seems something is going bizaar here.  clean db with each install, no cache in browser or var